# How to select column twice in query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a query that is really long (about 50 columns), I don't want to split into 2 queries. But I want a column to show up twice. Is there a way to do this? below is a simple example that doesn't work.

How to select B twice? The ability to select something twice is pretty standard in any SQL right?

`=query(B3:D7,"select B,C,B",0)`

Answer (score 4):

According to Google Help, the selected column must be an identifier, so it seems select a column twice is not possible within google query language.

Source: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#select

However, if your query is not too complex, you can cheat using aggreagation operators.

**If your column B is a number:**

`=query(B3:D7,"select B,C,B+0",0)`

**If your column B is a string:**

There is no neutral operator, but upper or lower can be usefull if the case isn't an issue for you.

`=query(B3:D7,"select B,C,UPPER(B)",0)`

If you use label, you'll have to respect the same identifier syntax used in your select clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to make a column to appear twice, instead of QUERY use an array.

```
={B3:B7,C3:C7,B3:B7}
```

If you will do some more complex, you could use the above array as the first argument of QUERY, but doing so, instead of using A, B, C notation for columns, use Col1, Col2, Col3.

Reference

- [Using arrays is Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: But this syntax is for vertical combination, not columns side to side. me wrong? OK, difference between ; and ,

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Are you trying to say my answer is unclear? Have you already read the reference?